# Is there a way to change Facebook's FBProfilePictureView Default Logged Out Profile Image?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS game that I'm working on that uses Facebook Login and  **FBProfilePictureView** to add the user's profile photo to the game when they are logged in.  When they are not logged in, the default Facebook Profile image shows instead.  Is there a way to customize or change that logged out default image to something else?

Here's an example of the image that I want to change.

[image: Example of the Default Facebook Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBProfilePictureView is a subclass of UIView. To put a custom picture in it you can use

```
profilePictureView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"]];
```

if the image is included in the project.

Answer (score 1):

I created an improved version of FBProfilePictureView [here](https://github.com/combinatorial/DBFBProfilePictureView). This allows you to specify the not logged in image directly.

```
DBFBProfilePictureView *facebookPictureView = [[DBFBProfilePictureView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
facebookPictureView.emptyImage = customImage;
```